# Change default keyboard layout for virtual terminal

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

I use customized keyboard layout, which was set to default in UI gnome settings. It works well in gnome.

However, when I open a new virtual termnial (`Ctrl+Shift+F4` or`Ctrl+Shift+F5` ) It does not use my prefered layout :(

Any idea how to make my layout the default everywhere ?

PS: When I was on uubntu 20, it was everywhere by default.
Now I ugraded to ubuntu 22 (and I'm using X11 server) and this problem appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the `/etc/default/keyboard` file to your liking. If you are not sure how to do it manually, there is a tool for the purpose:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Comment: Thanks, worked well  ! 
BTW, for anyone willing to go this route, it's wise to ensure you have another machine capable of ssh'ing into the one you're modifying, to ensure you don't lock yourself out because of a defective keyboard config

Comment: See also `localectl` for any system running systemd (basically any modern linux distribution).